# Is it possible to loop through a RegEx Range using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was thinking to myself, is it possible to loop through a RegEx range in JavaScript. Say for instance I wanted to loop through each letter of the alphabet, I could do something like this:

```
var theAlphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
[].forEach.call(theAlphabet, function (a) {
    console.log(a);
});
```

Please note that I know I could have done this by using `.split()` on the string and then looping, but anyway I was wondering if instead of a string I could a use a RegEx range, something like this (I know it doesn't work)

```
var reg = new RegExp(/A-Z/), result;
while((result = reg.exec(reg)) !== null) {
    console.log(result); // ["A-Z", index: 1, input: "/A-Z/"] - Not correct I realise
}
```

It's just something I was wondering. If this is a silly question say so and I shall remove it.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Regex looks for a pattern in a sequence, so a range has no real form until you use it in a query. Added to that, when you run a regex, you get a single result, so (my best guess - I've not written JS for years), your while loop would simply dump the entire result as one string. You would still have to split and iterate to get individual chars. I'd be very surprised if this behaved the way you would like, but even if it did work, it's not a particularly efficient way to do it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, I just thought that with a defined range, for example A-Z, mistakes are less likely than when we create a string with all the characters, not to worry...

Comment: From my experience, you're more likely to get errors as a result of using RegEx. It's notoriously difficult to write efficient RegEx queries, and it's very easy to write a query that is slow. If you have a string of all alphabetical chars, just stick them in their own JS file, and reference it whenever you need it. Then, it you're worries about mistakes (which is a sensible thing to be cautious of, so kudos), get somebody else to proof read your code before you deploy it anywhere. Unless you really need to parse something from a string, RegEx is best avoided.

Answer (score 3):

The question is rather unclear but I think you are asking if you can replace split with RegEx. You CAN do this of course, but two things come to mind.

You keep calling new regex for each letter which is going to have some performance overhead. If you do it like in this link: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split/2 its obviously better than split. This may not be the same with every language but it seems to be in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over a regex.  A regex can be matched or tested against a string but without the string there is no result.